# upload large file to database is correct practise?

Tags: java, mysql, file-upload, ftp

I am developing java web application, where users will upload video,image,document etc. my doubt is whether uploading file to database is a correct practice or uploading file to ftp and saving the path in database is correct practice.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to store only the file path in the database and check out this

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database